# How do I properly license Google Play Services?

Tags: google-play-services

I'm currently developing an app that uses some Google Play Services. I can't seem to find what information I need to display to say I used their software. Does anyone know what I should display?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal advice.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is in the wrong place, figured it would be a good place to start. Where should I ask about this? Any ideas?

Comment: This link about [App Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) may help you on how to properly license your app. It says:  "Google Play offers a licensing service that lets you enforce licensing policies for applications that you publish on Google Play. With Google Play Licensing, your application can query Google Play at run time to obtain the licensing status for the current user, then allow or disallow further use as appropriate."

Comment: @gerardnimo That's not quite what I'm trying to do. I'm more wondering what acknowledgement I need to put in my app since I am using a part of Google Play Services.

Comment: [oss licenses plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource) may help you generate legal notices for all your dependencies